VS Code - Unable to launch browser. "spawn C:\Program Files\Google\Application\chrome.exe ENOENT"
i was trying to debug an HTML file in Visual Studio Code using the debugger (launch.json). It has always worked fine, but now I’m getting this error:
Unable to launch browser: "spawn C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe ENOENT"
Here is my launch.json:
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        
        {
            "name": "Launch Chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "chrome",
            "url": "http://localhost:8080",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}\\Test\\index.html"
        }
        
    ]
}

This issue started suddenly, literally within a one-minute difference, without me changing nothing. I’m not sure what’s causing the issue or how to fix it.
Could anyone help me troubleshoot this? Thanks in advance.
I tried to:
Restart VS Code to see if it was a temporary issue.
Specify the exact path to chrome.exe in the launch.json.
Recreate the launch.json file multiple times, hoping it was a bug or a mistake in the configuration.
I was expecting the debugger to open Chrome and load the specified HTML file, as it always did. Instead, nothing happened, and the error persisted.
